# How to search by any field with pagination

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a use case where i need to find paginated list of customers, where customer looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phone;

    private String mail;
}
```

then i have my repository interface

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {

Optional<Customer> findById(Long id);
...
}
```

my interface extends PagingAndSortingRepository to provide pageable result.

I also have an input box where user can put any String. Now i want to return him a page of results which contain input string in one of the fields (any of customers fields).

I don't want to use named queries. Is there a smart way in which i can achieve this with PagingAndSortingRepository repository or do i need to use Specification interface and implement pagination?

Comment: how about datatable from bootstrap?

Comment: @soorapadman i need the search to be done on server side for efficiency reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where c.firstName like :filter" 
           + " or c.lastName like :filter or c.emailAddress like :filter.......")
Page<Customer> filter(@Param("filter") String filter);
```

Alternately you can use QueryDsl.

Extend the additional Interface:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer>{

}
```

Add the relevant build tools:

You can then call the inherited method :

```
Page<Customer> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)
```

used like:

```
Page<Customer> page =repo.findAll(QCustomer.customer.firstName.like(filter)
     .or(QCustomer.customer.lastName.like(filter).or(...));
```

References:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: unfortunately one fo requirements is to not use @Querry

Comment: Why on earth would you have such a ridiculous requirement?